# Need help for the definition of timer function

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, atmega, timer, atmel-studio

I've found below code that belongs to the timer declaration function but the definition is hidden by the author.
Can anyone help me to provide a definition for the same?

I want this to be utilized in a project related to **ATMEGA8 timer using Atmel studio**.

```
#ifndef TIMERS_H_

#define TIMERS_H_

#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct timer_st_
{
    volatile uint8_t    expiry_flag:1;
    volatile uint8_t    enabled_flag:1;
    uint16_t            ticks_elapsed;
    uint16_t            ticks_total;
}timer_st;

void
reset_timer (timer_st *timer);

void
start_timer (timer_st *timer, uint16_t ticks);

void
stop_timer (timer_st *timer);

uint8_t
is_timer_expired (timer_st *timer);

uint8_t
is_timer_enabled (timer_st *timer);

void
process_timer (timer_st *timer);
#endif /* TIMERS_H_ */
```

Comment: Hi! "I found": you need to state *where* you found it, and who the original author is. Not only is this a common standard for courtesy, it's also required by terms of services on this site.

Comment: Wouldn't this question be placed better at *Stack Overflow*? Apparently it's rather about µC programming than about electrical engineering.

Comment: @Neppomuk - Hi, FYI MCU firmware programming is [on-topic](/help/on-topic) here. Even if it would also be on-topic at SO, that doesn't mean that it's *not* on-topic here too.

Answer (score 2):

It seems straightforward enough:

- `reset_timer (timer_st *timer)` clears `enabled_flag` and `ticks_elapsed`
- `start_timer (timer_st *timer, uint16_t ticks)` clears `expiry_flag` and `ticks_elaped`, sets `ticks_total = ticks` and sets `enabled_flag`
- `stop_timer (timer_st *timer)` clears `enabled_flag`
- `is_timer_expired (timer_st *timer)` returns `expiry_flag`
- `is_timer_enabled (timer_st *timer)` returns `enabled_flag`

The last one, `process_timer (timer_st *timer)`, does the work of updating the timer periodically. Presumably, it would be called from a hardware timer ISR for each timer in the system. If the timer is enabled and not expired, it increments `ticks_elapsed`, and if it is now greater than or equal to `ticks_total`, it also sets `expiry_flag`.

Comment: would it be possible to get this in C embedded code?

Comment: No. If you can't write the C code from the descriptions I wrote, There isn't much hope for your ability to use this in your application.